Have some colleges shown tendency to meet the demands of protesters other than Trinity College?
Trinity College Dublin agreed to divest from Israeli firms acquiescing to the demands of the students' protest. It was the first college to meet such demands after college protests broke out across the world from America and Canada to Europe, India, and Australia. In the United States, there have been police intervention and forceful ending to some protests.
What is the current progress of the ongoing protests? Have other colleges than Trinity College signaled that they will agree to the demands of protesting students?

I think this is fairly comprehensively answered by the 'Impact' section on the Wikipedia page

The Guardian did an explainer that summarises some responses. I don't see the utility in writing a proper answer on a fast-changing topic.

Columbia State University has a Socially Responsible Investment Policy that forbids them from investing in oil and gas, private prisons, coal, and tobacco. I wouldn't be surprised if at least some of those restrictions were the results of protests. But you would have to go through the meeting notes of the responsible organizations to find out, I imagine.

This is an ongoing process and we can expect more to join Trinity at some point.  First thing:  do we want to track this in real-time, given a wiki page that does so?  Second, as phrased, and with periodic additions to the list, answers will quickly give the impression that divesting is the norm.  However, what will not be apparent is how many universities refuse to carry out divestment.  Might be a better Q in a few years: "how many universities have divested since 2024?".  But for now, is it a good fit?  If not, what would be the reason for closure?  I started answering then deleted.


Question:
Have some colleges shown tendency to meet the demands of protesters other than Trinity College?

Northwestern
Brown
University of Minnesota
Evergreen State College
The University of California, Riverside
Thompson Rivers University

Pro-Palestine protests: How some universities reached deals with students



Northwestern University, based in Illinois, US struck a deal with its protesting students on April 29 to take down most of the tents. It allowed them, however, to continue their protest – just not through an encampment – until June 1. The university promised to provide students with ways to engage with the Investment Committee of the Board of Trustees, including re-establishing an advisory committee on investment responsibility in the fall (autumn). The advisory committee could consider divestment proposals from university members. The institute agreed to disclose its investments through its endowment funds to “internal stakeholders”, which include current students, faculty, staff and trustees. Northwestern also agreed to cover education at the university for five Palestinian undergraduate students.
Brown University in Rhode Island agreed on April 30 that the Corporation, Brown’s highest governing body, would vote on divestment from companies affiliated with Israel during a meeting in October. In return, students cleared the encampments that had been in place since April 24.
Also on April 30, students and administrators at Evergreen State College in Washington agreed to a pact. Students removed a week-long encampment. The university set up task forces to assess – among other things – investment policies and the possibility of divestment, and look at whether the school’s policies regarding grants help governments engaged in illegal occupations abroad.
On May 1, the University of Minnesota announced a compromise under which it promised to provide protesters with information on public companies it has invested in. However, the university made it clear that non-disclosure agreements barred it from disclosing information about private companies that the school has invested in. It added that the administration had recommended to the University’s police department that it avoid arresting student protesters. However, the university said it will not ban employers from career fairs because it does not “support restricting student career opportunities”. Students had been demanding that firms with ties to Israel not be invited.
Student protesters from Rutgers University in New Jersey reached an agreement with the administration on May 2. The university agreed to create an Arab cultural centre and hire staff and instructors who have knowledge about Palestinian communities alongside naming Palestine, Palestinians and Gaza in future communications. It also agreed to work with students, faculty and staff to support 10 displaced Palestinian students to complete their education at Rutgers. No students, staff or faculty involved in the encampment will face retaliation, the university promised. The students’ request for divestment is also under review.
University of Minnesota in the UK reached an agreement on May 3 after students set up encampments in the university’s library. Goldsmiths agreed to a new ethical investment policy. The protesting student group will have an opportunity to present their “evidence of Goldsmiths’ complicity with Israel” to the institute’s finance committee. Goldsmiths also agreed to name one of the media department’s lecture theatres after Shireen Abu Akleh, an Al Jazeera reporter who was killed by Israeli forces while she was on assignment in the West Bank. The institute will also conduct a review of the International Holocaust Remembrance Alliance (IHRA) definition of anti-Semitism which critics have described as so broad as to effectively bar most criticism of Israel.
The University of California, Riverside (UCR) issued a statement on May 3 saying an agreement has been reached to peacefully end the encampments. The university announced it would publish several details of its investments online. UCR’s School of Business has also discontinued multiple global programmes, including those in Israel. Students also want the university to ban the sale of Sabra Hummus, a packaged hummus brand owned by PepsiCo and the Israel-based Strauss Group, from campus. The university said it would review the demand.
Thompson Rivers University (TRU) in Canada’s British Columbia also saw an agreement on Saturday, May 4, following negotiations, making it the first Canadian institute to see a deal. TRU’s student group called the People’s University of Gaza at TRU did not have encampments and began their push towards divestment through an email sent to the administration on April 30, a TRU student protester wrote in a statement to Al Jazeera. The TRU administration has agreed to disclose their investments within 30 days of the students filing a Freedom of Information (FOI) request. A student at TRU told Al Jazeera that they have already filed the request. Once TRU discloses its investments, students will draft a divestment proposal. However, TRU has refused to publicly condemn and demand an end to “acts of genocide in Gaza,” which was one of the students’ demands. “We will continue to engage with the institution on this matter,” a press release by the People’s University of Gaza at TRU said.


